# Join Facebook Event from Android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am displaying some Facebook events in a list inside my Android app and I was wondering if it was possible for a user to join a Facebook event while being in my app?

If yes, how do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible via the `/{event_id}/attending` edge.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/event/attending#publish